# Why java clone() method requires unchecked cast?

Tags: java, object, casting, clone, unchecked

This code snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> mif = new HashMap<>();
        mif.put(2, "haha");
        mif.put(3, "hello");
        mif.put(1, "hi");
        HashMap<Integer, String> mifClone = mif.clone(); // compile error
```

The last line doesn't compile, saying that:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to HashMap<Integer,String>
```

So I changed to

```
        HashMap<Integer, String> mifClone = (HashMap<Integer, String>)mif.clone(); // warning
```

This time it becomes a warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to HashMap<Integer,String> Java(16777761)
```

My question:

(1) Java compiler knows that `mif` has specified type, why "clone()" still returns an "Object" instead of `HashMap<Integer, String>` type?

(2) How to fix the "unchecked" warning, without suppressing it?

Comment: 1) It does NOT know that `clone` returns a `HashMap`.  `Object` is not a generic type, and the return type of `clone()` is `Object`.  Check the javadoc.  Note that if they changed this, it would most likely break millions of existing Java programs.

Comment: 2) Use `new HashMap<>(mif)` instead.  As a general rule you should avoid using `clone()`, especially if there is a more specific alternative ... with better defined semantics.  (Read the javadoc for `clone` to get a gist of what I mean about semantics ...)

Comment: 1a) Note that `HashMap` is not `final`.  So someone could declare a subclass of `HashMap` where `clone` returned (say) an `Integer` rather than a `HashMap` subclass.  The cast is necessary.

Comment: @StephenC This explanation really makes sense.

Comment: Yes. But 1) trumps 1a).  The Java compiler does not know anything about how the class libraries choose to implement `HashMap.clone()`.  All it knows is that the `HashMap` API says `Object` is the return type. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#clone--